# Return DataTable from ORACLE

Tags: oracle, datatable

I'm trying to get data from Oracle to a Datatable. My idea was to create a function to do all connection staff and then call it from other parts of the code.

Like:

```
 dt = New DataTable
 dt = Oracle2table(sql.ToString)
```

Then, I created the function:

```
Function Oracle2table(ByVal sql As String) As DataTable

    Oracle2table = Nothing

    Try
        conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString)

        conn.Open()

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)

        adaptador = New OleDbDataAdapter
        adaptador.SelectCommand = cmd

        adaptador.Fill(Oracle2table)

        conn.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error al cargar la tabla. ERROR = " + ex.ToString)

    Finally

        Oracle2table = Nothing

    End Try

End Function
```

The problem with this code is initialize the variable (*Oracle2table = nothing*) so i didn't receive a function error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not VB specialist, but this code worked fine, so it may be useful for you:

```
Dim dt = Oracle2table("select * from dual")
Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows(0)(0))
```

Function (I removed exception handling for simplicity):

```
Function Oracle2table(ByVal sql As String) As DataTable
    Dim conn = New OleDbConnection(connString)

    Oracle2table = New DataTable
    conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)

    Dim adaptador = New OleDbDataAdapter
    adaptador.SelectCommand = cmd
    adaptador.Fill(Oracle2table)
    conn.Dispose()
End Function
```